# gnosis-safe access not possible with the https://gnosis-safe.io/

Tags: gnosis-safe

We have a safe; which we created back last year. today when we wanted to log back in, seems like things have changed. We got the message on the safe app; that it was created using the binance fork, so they won't be able to help out.

So what would be easiest way to get excess to those funds. We are not that technical to work with SC, so if there would be an alternative and if you guys can help or share a link would be nice.